# htaccess on wordpress : why http to https doesn't seem to work

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to always access wordpress admin with https. I use this (copied and paste from a blog I read)

```
    # Redirection to HTTPS 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirection from www to non-www HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That doesn't work. I always have to modify the url by hand in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "RewriteEngine on" at the first line, I'd also remove the condition "%{HTTPS} =off" as the condition "%{SERVER_PORT} 80" should be good enough.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```